# How far will a Golden Snitch travel during a match?

Tags: harry-potter

In the third Harry Potter movie (The Prisoner of Azkaban) the Snitch flies extremely high. It flies so high that the Quidditch arena falls out of view.

Just how far will a Snitch travel? Will it stay in the area of the match or is its flight random, and thus it could potentially just leave the game area completely, never to return?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The Golden Snitch, as Bowman called his invention, was a walnut-sized ball exactly the weight of a Snidget. Its silvery wings had rotational joints like the Snidget’s, enabling it to change direction with the lightning speed and precision of its living model. **Unlike the Snidget, however, the Snitch had been bewitched to remain within the boundaries of the field**.
>   <sub>*Quidditch Through the Ages* - pages 14-15 - Scholastic Books</sub>
>   and:
>   Though there is **no limit imposed on the height to which a player may rise during the game**, he or she must not stray over the boundary lines of the pitch.
>   <sub>*Quidditch Through the Ages* - page 27 - Scholastic Books</sub>

I'll check to see if there's any more info and edit if so.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: @BorhanMooz - Thanks! Short, and straight to the point :)

Comment: Congrats on exactly 83k!

Comment: Someone should probably have told the filmmakers about the whole "don't go outside the pitch" rule... I seem to recall a scene in (I think?) CoS where Harry and Draco chased the snitch under the stands.